# Suggestion to resolve an enum ambiguity name clash?

Tags: c++, enums, namespaces

I have a library in a codebase with something like the following:

```
namespace rat {

   ...

   enum myEnum {
      BLUE,
      RED
   }

   ...
} //namespace rat
```

later on I try to compile an app in the codebase using the library before and it warns me of an ambiguity when i use namespace rat (the codebase main namespace) saying that BLUE could either be `rat::myEnum` `rat::BLUE` or `rat::enums::Freq` `rat::enums::BLUE` from some other file I'm not familiar with (and isn't mine) that has an enum Freq with a guy called BLUE in namespace enums within namespace rat...

Is there a way in the user code to say which one I want at the moment? Or do i have to nest mylibs enum in say namespace mylib and then say either rat::enums::BLUE or rat::mylib::BLUE ?

Comment: If you have C++11, `enum class` creates a new scope.

Comment: So, where did you put the `using namespace` directives?  It appears that all of the compiler complaints are in seperate namespaces (`rat`, `rat::enums`).

Comment: I don't have C++11, and and the application has a using namespace rat. This brings into scope my myEnum and enums::Freq both of which contain BLUE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The full unambiguous name of the enum constants will be `::rat::BLUE`, `::rat::enums::BLUE`, etc.

Remember that the `::` at the beginning of the expression stands for the *global namespace*.

Answer (score 4):

What I typically do in C++03 (pre C++11!) is to nest `enum`s in `struct`s, so they don't leak out:

```
namespace rat {
  struct myEnum {
    enum Enum {
      blue, red
    };
  };
}
```

You will have to define variables as `rat::myEnum::Enum` and values as `rat::myEnum::blue`, but typically `myEnum` should be something meaningful like `Color`, so the naming is not redundant.

This emulates the C++11 `class enum`s in a way, so you should use these, if you have access to a C++11 compiler.